# How to read data tables stored in text files (*.rtf, *.doc, *.docx, *.dat) using Odbc?

Tags: c#, odbc

I have multiple files having data files stored in them. 
I want to read them with Odbc or jet engine and stored them into DataSets. 
Any ideas how to do that?

I wrote this code but I get error that file is read only:

```
            tring strConnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dirCSV + @";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""; 

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", fileNevCSV);
            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds2);
```

Comment: I suspect you need interop, not odbc.

Comment: Do you mean reading line by line?

Comment: can you please give me more hints?

Comment: For example, you can select each table object in docx with for each table in activedocument.tables. It is a bit difficult to say when I do not know what the data is or how it is organized.

Comment: Thanks I am going to try it now